# Plugged in not charging

Tags: laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad E430.

I have installed Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

My battery charges up to 46%, and then it is showing "plugged in, but not charging".

I tried many possibilities.

```
1. Uninstalled AC Adapter control 
2. Removed battery for some time
3. Shutdown, Connected AC adapter, Uninstall AC Adapter control, Connect Battery
4. Reset Gauge on energy management (It takes long time to reset).
```

But these did not fix the problem.

Can some one point out the solutions for this one?

Comment: How old is your battery?  It is possible that you only have 46% battery life available in the battery.  You may need to consider purchasing a new battery.  If it is under warranty, I would call Lenovo and have them send you one.  If not, purchase a new battery and see if that solves the issue.  If it doesn't you can always return the battery.

Comment: The e430 came out in about 2012.  If you've never replaced your battery, then it should be your first suspect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laptop battery indicator saying "plugged in, not charging"](http://superuser.com/questions/552884/laptop-battery-indicator-saying-plugged-in-not-charging), and [Notebook computer battery says: plugged in but not charging with no further information. Is the battery bad already?](http://superuser.com/questions/101213/notebook-computer-battery-says-plugged-in-but-not-charging-with-no-further-info?rq=1)

Comment: What power scheme are you using? Battery conservation mode will maintain it around 50% full.

Comment: Im in balanced mode not in conservation mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is [by design](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht078208) on some Lenovo laptops, including yours. Charging your battery to about 50% will increase its lifespan compared to a full charge. You should keep this setting if your laptop is on mains power most of the time, and when it's not, you don't need it to work on battery for a long time.

In order to disable this setting:

1. run Lenovo Power Manager (usually a double click on the battery icon will do)
2. switch to advanced mode and go to Battery tab
3. click "Battery Maintenance..." button
4. select "Always fully charge" option

If you don't have or don't use Lenovo Power Manager, you should be able to set charging thresholds via the registry. For Windows 8, the procedure is described in the following topic on [Lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1-Knowledge-Base/Changing-Charge-Threshold-on-ThinkPads-under-Windows-8-without/ta-p/920657):

> Find the registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\PWRMGRV\Data]`
>
> You should see 4 entries that are currently set to 0: `ChargeStartControl`, `ChargeStartPercentage`, `ChargeStopControl`, `ChargeStopPercentage`.
>
> The first 2 entries, `ChargeStartControl` and `ChargeStartPercentage`, change the starting charge threshold.
>   The second 2 entries, `ChargeStopControl` and `ChargeStopPercentage`, change the stopping threshold.

The values of these entries are logical values and decimal percents, respectively. For example, to start charging your battery at 40% and stop charging at 80%, you should set `ChargeStartControl` and `ChargeStopControl` to 1, `ChargeStartPercentage` to 40 and  `ChargeStopPercentage` to 80.

Don't forget to restart your computer to make the changes effective.

**Be aware that this method does not seem to work for all users.**